# Swift Tableview cell re-appear after deletion

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, tableview

I am working on a twitter clone and I connected my app to firebase to read and write the posts. However, when I delete a cell the animation starts and the deletion actually happens from my posts array. The problem is when I try to delete another post the post I already deleted re-appears for some reason.

Here are some screenshots of what is happening:

First I delete a post and everything is normal.

[deleting a post](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tVLna.png)

Then the post is deleted

[deleted post](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BjkPh.png)

now I try to delete another post

[deleting another post](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3wnlH.png)

Then the older post re-appears in the place of the last post deleted.

[deleted post reappears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W1Hg9.png)
This continues until I get an index out of bounds exception when I attempt to delete all the cells.

As seen from the screenshots, I delete the cells from a delete button which is why I need a callback from the cell.

Here is my code for the cell and for the "Home Screen"

class PostTableViewCell: UITableViewCell, UITextViewDelegate{

```
var didDelete : ((UITableViewCell) -> Void)?

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

    // Initialization code

}

func set(post: Post){
    username.text = post.username
    postText.text = post.text
    timestamp.text = post.createdAt.calenderTimeSinceNow()
    postId = post.id
    
    setPopupMenu(post: post)
}

func setPopupMenu(post: Post){
    let options = { (action: UIAction) in
        print(action.title)
        
 if(action.title == "Delete"){
            // delete post
            self.didDelete!(self)

        }
    }
    menuButton.showsMenuAsPrimaryAction = true
  }
}
```

and this is the Home Screen code :

```
class HomeViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{

let cellNib = UINib(nibName: "PostTableViewCell", bundle: nil)

var posts = [Post]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.register(cellNib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "postCell")
    
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    
    
    readPosts()
    
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
}

func  tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return posts.count
}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "postCell", for: indexPath) as! PostTableViewCell
    cell.set(post: posts[indexPath.row])

    
    cell.didDelete = { aCell in
        
        self.progressView.isHidden = false
        
        let currentIndexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: aCell)!
        
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        db.collection("Posts").document(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid).collection("Posts").document(cell.postId).delete() { err in
            
            self.progressView.isHidden = false
            
            if let err = err {
                
                print("Error removing document: \(err)")
            } else {
                self.posts.remove(at: indexPath.row)
                tableView.deleteRows(at: [currentIndexPath], with: .automatic)
                self.progressView.isHidden = true
            }
           
        }
        
    }
    
    return cell
}

func readPosts(){
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    
    db.collection("Posts").addSnapshotListener { documentSnapshot, error in
       guard let document = documentSnapshot else {
         print("Error fetching document: \(error!)")
         return
       }
        var tempPosts = [Post]()
        for doc in documentSnapshot!.documents{
            db.collection("Posts").document(doc.documentID).collection("Posts").order(by: "timestamp").addSnapshotListener { documentSnapshot, error in
                
                for docu in documentSnapshot!.documents {
                    
                    let daate = docu.data()["timestamp"] as! Timestamp
                    let mydbl = daate.dateValue().timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000

                    let post = Post(id: docu.documentID, username: "@\(docu.data()["username"]!)", userId: doc.documentID , text: docu.data()["text"] as! String, timestamp: mydbl , numLikes: 0, numReposts: 0)
                    
                    let isDuplicate = tempPosts.contains(where: { $0.id == post.id })

                    if(!isDuplicate){
                        tempPosts.insert(post, at: 0)
                    }
                }
                self.posts.removeAll()
                self.posts = tempPosts
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
        self.progressView.isHidden = true
        
    }
}
}
```

Note that when I comment out the firebase document deletion part everything works fine and the deleted document is not re produced

Comment: Just a guess here but it may be the order in which things are being done. You're reading in your firebase data and adding a listener `addSnapshotListener` to that data. What that means is; when the data changes, and event is fired. So. There lies the confusion - when a post is deleted, all of the data is re-read? Is that intentional? If so, then there is a possibility that what was at index 3 a moment ago, is not loger at index 3 because all of the data was reread? Can you clarify?

Comment: I just want to delete the cell visually and delete the firebase document. How would that be done? Remove the snapshot listener?

Comment: Well sure. If you just want to load the data and not worry about listening for changes, just use `getDocuments` and avoid the listener. Otherwise what's generally done is to not do anything with the dataSource directly. Simply delete the object from Firebase, which will cause an event to fire, which will then reload the tableView with the updated data.

Comment: Would getDocuments listen for changes and update the values when a document is deleted?

Comment: No. But that's the point - it seems your performing the same task twice as it is.... removing it from the array in code, but also removing it from Firebase at the same time, which results in and event firing which reloads the data from Firebase, which would not contain the deleted item.